# MySql join duplicate values in columns having distinct records

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: Artist and play_store. Artist table has 2 columns id (PK), name. play_store table has columns: id(pk), title, artist_id (-> the foreign key of artist table pk) .

Artist table

```
id  | name  
1   | ArtistA  
2   | ArtistB  
3   | ArtistC  
4   | ArtistD
```

play_store table

```
id |  title | artist_id   
1  | TitleA | 1   
2  | TitleB | 2   
3  | TitleA | 2    
4  | TitleC | 3   
5  | TitleC | 4
```

In above play_store table, duplicate Titles are available with different artist_id s. I want to omit those duplicate titles but need all different artist_id s in a response column. The expected results should be as following.

```
id |  title | artist_id  
1  | TitleA | 1,2  
2  | TitleB | 2  
3  | TitleC | 3,4
```

Can anyone let me know how to join the duplicate values into one column but still having distinct records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT title, group_concat(artist_id) as artist_ids 
FROM `play_store`
GROUP BY title
```

Note that there's no `id` column as that's not present in the `group by` and shouldn't be selected. If you want a "counter" as well,

```
SET @counter = 0; 
SELECT 
    (@counter := @counter +1) as counter,  
    title, 
    group_concat(artist_id) as artist_ids 
FROM `play_store`
GROUP BY title
```